# Expression Blend 3 Default Images Location Problem

Tags: wpf, expression

I'm using Expression Blend 3 to do the visual side of our project.  In the project, we have a folder, named "Images", which we want to use to contain all of our image data.  In Expression, though, whenever we add a new image, it adds it directly to the project root, and has all references to the image pointed there.  Currently, we do all the stuff in Expression, and then, when done, manually move the images and update all the references by hand (well, by find/replace).  Is there any way to change Expression's default location to the Images folder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any way to set a default location other than the root.

I typically move all the media resources I'll need into the appropriate folders in Visual Studio, or just do it in the file system and include them in the project using Visual Studio.

Then in Blend they are all available in the folders where I want them, and no changes to references are necessary.